# Call Environment.IsDevelopment() before building WebApplication in Asp.Net core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an Asp.net core 7 application.
Is there an analog of method `app.Environment.IsDevelopment()` before building the `WebApplication`?

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Can I call IsDevelopment() here?

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //...
}
```

I know that I can use Environment Variable, but I wanted to know if there is an already existing standard approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there an analog of method `app.Environment.IsDevelopment()` before
> building the `WebApplication`?

Yes:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var isDevelopment = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment();

// ...
```